The error "Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - config/puma.rb" occurs when I try to deploy rails docker container to Heroku
I try to deploy a rails docker container to Heroku, but the error

Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen -
config/puma.rb**"

occurs after I execute "heroku open -a [My app
name]" and "**heroku logs --tail -a [MyApp name]
My Ruby version is 2.7.8
My Rails version is 6.0.6.1
Gemfile
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.7.8'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails', branch: 'main'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.6', '>= 6.0.6.1'
# Use mysql as the database for Active Record
gem 'mysql2', '>= 0.4.4'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 4.1'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
# gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use Active Model has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Active Storage variant
# gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.2', require: false

# Use Rack CORS for handling Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS), making cross-origin AJAX possible
gem 'rack-cors'

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

gem 'rest-client'

puma.rb
workers Integer(ENV['WEB_CONCURRENCY'] || 2)
threads_count = Integer(ENV['RAILS_MAX_THREADS'] || 5)
threads threads_count, threads_count

preload_app!

rackup      DefaultRackup
port        ENV['PORT']     || 3000
environment ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'development'

on_worker_boot do
  # Worker specific setup for Rails 4.1+
  # See: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-rails-applications-with-the-puma-web-server#on-worker-boot
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end

heroku.yml
build:
  docker:
    web: Dockerfile
run:
  web: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb

terminal(Current level)
[project root] % ls
Dockerfile  Rakefile    db      storage
Gemfile     app     heroku.yml  test
Gemfile.lock    bin     lib     tmp
Procfile    config      log     vendor
README.md   config.ru   public
[project root] % cd config
[project root] config % ls
application.rb      environment.rb      puma.rb
boot.rb         environments        routes.rb
cable.yml       initializers        spring.rb
credentials.yml.enc locales         storage.yml
database.yml        master.key

part of error log after "heroku open -a [My app name]" and "heroku logs --tail -a [MyApp name]"
2024-05-23T15:03:36.654371+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2024-05-23T15:03:36.678218+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2024-05-23T15:05:24.931463+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=spots-post-c6b45a4ea994.herokuapp.com request_id=f84e0b95-cb13-453d-a5a2-88c96ecbd0b4 fwd="175.177.48.50" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2024-05-23T15:05:25.165569+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=spots-post-c6b45a4ea994.herokuapp.com request_id=23421715-774c-45f9-b010-6356eebc3c23 fwd="175.177.48.50" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2024-05-23T15:25:34.216822+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2024-05-23T15:25:51.774950+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `/bin/sh -c bundle\ exec\ puma\ -C\ config/puma.rb`
2024-05-23T15:25:52.861364+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2024-05-23T15:25:52.807596+00:00 app[web.1]: bundler: failed to load command: puma (/usr/local/bundle/bin/puma)
2024-05-23T15:25:52.807699+00:00 app[web.1]: Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - config/puma.rb
2024-05-23T15:25:52.807699+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bundle/gems/puma-4.3.12/lib/puma/dsl.rb:46:in `read'
2024-05-23T15:25:52.807699+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bundle/gems/puma-4.3.12/lib/puma/dsl.rb:46:in `_load_from'

I checked levels of heroku.yml and puma.rb are appropriate, and those two are committed. However, I'm not confident of content of puma.rb.
Can you see any problems from my situation?

Add your ruby and rails versions to the question

Sorry, I added them to my question.
